# How to remove a label from a mail by using gmail gem

Tags: ruby, gmail

I'm using `gmail` gem and I want to remove a label from a email, but I couldn't find out how to remove the label.

By this code I can remove label itself.

```
gmail.labels.delete("Urgent")
```

But I want to remove a label from a email like this.

```
email.remove_label('Urgent')
```

How can I do it by using `gmail` gem?

https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

Comment: [`Message#remove_label`](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail/blob/c5e938942675fb3a3f71fa957e299a1cd1ee1577/lib/gmail/message.rb#L155) seems to be just right. Did you get an error?

Comment: I didn't tried the method. I should have tried it. Thanks!